# OpenChrom - IDE user product not showing up in Eclipse Installer simple mode

Tags: eclipse, oomph, openchrom

I am following OpenChrom's development instructions on their wiki (https://wiki.openchrom.net/index.php/Development). I've been able to add the user product in advanced mode, but the next step is to switch to simple mode and install the IDE but it's not showing up as an option. I can install it in advanced mode but I keep getting the error below:

[image: OpenChrome - IDE advanced mode installation error]

How can I get the user product to show up in simple mode? Or how I can successfully install the IDE in advanced mode?

Answer (score 0):

This doc is outdated.
Please have a look here:
https://github.com/OpenChrom/openchrom/wiki/Quickstart